# Is it safe to use std::vector.erase(begin(), end()) or std::vector.erase(begin(), begin())?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to process elements from a vector for some time. To optimize this I don't want to remove an item when it is processed and I remove all processed items at the end.

```
vector<Item*>::iterator it;
for(it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it)
{
    DoSomething(*it);

    if(TimeIsUp())
    {
        break;
    }
}

items.erase(items.begin(), it);
```

Is it safe to use erase when `it == items.end()`? In documentaion it is said that `erase()` will erase [first,last) and this should be safe but I want to be sure.

EDIT:

Is it safe to use std::vector.erase(begin(), begin())?

Comment: I strongly advise against using a `vector` of regular pointers. Either use a container specifically designed to hold pointers or use a `vector` of smart pointers. (A possible exception would be if the vector doesn't own the objects it points to.)

Comment: @Cristy: I don't think that is really a duplicate, the other Q was about a crash because of incrementing an iterator beyond `end`. It only incidentially contains `erase` and `end`, too.

Comment: I do wonder why the vector can't be `clear`ed, though.

Comment: @Damon Because `it` may not always be equal to `items.end()`

Comment: @Praetorian: Oh how stupid of me... you're right. I've read "remove all elements afterwards" instead of "removed all **processed** elements".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What that `[first,last)` means is everything between `first` and `last`, including `first` but not including `last`. It denotes a half-open set. Had they used `[first,last]`, `last` would also be included; had they they used `(first,last)`, `first` and `last` would be excluded.

There is a problem with your code. You want the element at `it` to be deleted if `it` isn't equal to `end()`. Instead of `items.erase (items.begin(),it)`, you should be using

```
if (it != items.end()) {
   items.erase (items.begin(), it+1);
}
else {
   items.clear(); // same as items.erase (items.begin(), items.end())
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is correct - that's what the notation `[first, last)` means and `end()` points one past the end.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your edit: yes, that's fine too. `vec.erase(q1,q2)` is defined as erasing "the elements in the range `[q1, q2)`." Here, both arguments are the same. `[q1, q2)` is defined as being a valid range of const iterators. A range is considered to be valid if there is a sequence of increments you can do to `q1` to get to `q2` - in this case, the sequence has no increments. In fact, the standard specifically defines an empty range:

> A range `[i,i)` is an empty range